# What are .NET 5.0.2 and 5.0.4?

Tags: .net

Looking at the .SDK and runtime versions here: https://versionsof.net/core/5.0/ I noticed that 5.0.12 (runtime) is delivered with SDK version 5.0.209 and 5.0.403.

Why do the SDKs have two lines of versioning?

Comment: Ask Microsoft. They decide how their versioning is done.

Comment: .NET SDK is not just one thing, it contains base class library, the runtime, compiler, etc. As such, there can be different versions of the SDK, which packages everything into one package, which contains a mix and match of stuff. Most likely the .209 release is a security hotfix to a .20x version that contains a fix to the runtime, and possibly to the class library, but perhaps not the compiler. The .403 release can be a release which contains updates to everything. This... is just a guess. What @KenWhite is probably the only correct comment, Microsoft decides, you need to ask them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime versioning pattern follows the "semantic version" (semver.org): MAJOR.MINOR.PATH. The SDK does not follow this pattern as it is released faster. The SDK follows the standard: 1.2.345. the first position is the major version, the second is the minor version and the last 2 are the paths, the third position "communicates" with the minor and the paths. The major and minor versions of runtime and sdk are always released together. Now answering your question: The third position of the version number is updated with every feature release and the last two with every servicing update. Let's say they release a new feature, then version 5.0.500 would be created, but if there was only an update or service fix, it would just increment the path from 5.0.403 to 5.0.404. If this service that has been fixed or changed already exists in version 20x, then version 20x would also be incremented, in this case from 5.0.209 to 5.0.210. For the versions you mentioned, the 20x version changes have updates for the integration with visual studio sdk version 16.9.13 (version of the package with integration with visual studio) and the version 40x has for version 16.11.6 and consequently for the version 16.9.13.

See more details:

Overview of version implementation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/

.net proposals design:

https://github.com/dotnet/designs/pull/29/commits/2ccd167c7d89c3412ad6ed8e50918a6a7f275bf5#diff-fcef89dfb399c7ead275b2890d08d756f6c9a910b78f50fcaaa95f6c01135071